# Delete files from FAST_recovery_area

Tags: rman

I am trying to delete the old files from fast_recovery_area folder inside Oracle on Windows as I am running out of space. The database is not in archivelog mode. I am connecting to RMAN and using the following command. My query is - can I delete those files directly from disk?

[image]

Comment: It is preferred to have commands, error messages and the like edited directly into the question. Please avoid screenshots.

Comment: You are saying that the database is not in archivelog mode. Therefore, there should be no archivelogs in the FRA. You need to investigate what takes that much space. It could be a backup of the database. Please share the content and disk usage of the FRA.

Comment: "can I delete those files directly from disk" what files? All I see in the screenshot is "does not match" x 4. Are there any files inside the ARCHIVELOG folder? Do not delete the online log files.